Elevator force diagram

Am i correct when i say that all the seperate bodies and the whole system has to have 10m/s² acceleration?
So can i say : F=ma
For elevator : (T-R) = 10 × mass of elevator
For box : (R - 20N) = 10 × 2
For system : (T-20) = 10 × ( mass of elevator + 2kg )
Where R on the elevator is equal to the normal force on the box?
My main problem is where R comes in. As in is the R relevant to the elevator? I know that it is for the box.

I dont understand why the question is closed even though i created it so i can ask about the forces. Its not a "homework"
Problem


Am i correct when i say that all the separate bodies and the whole system has to have 10m/s² acceleration [upwards]? - Yes

Voting to reopen. This is a conceptual question and so allowed by policy.

For system there will also be gravitational force on the elevator so
$T-20-10m=10(2+m)$ where m is the mass of elevator and the acceleration due to gravity is approximated to be 10

@gandalf draw a free body diagram and you will understand that what has been added on the RHS is not the weight

You are correct. I have deleted my comment.

What about R? Thats my main issue

@Safayousif R is an internal force of the system so it will just cancel out

@YashShrivastava thats true if we see the system as a whole, but if we take each invidual peice as in the elevator on its own and the box on its own what cancels it then?

@Safayousif If we take it individually then it will not cancel out
